# page-break-inside order of priority

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set the order of priority for page breaks with CSS? So if an element has `page-break-inside: avoid` and element inside it also has the same, is it possible to say which should break first if a break is needed?

I'm working on a report where there are headers, sub headers and data and the view is created with handebars and can have varying amounts of data. I want to group the data as much as possible but absolutely want to avoid the situation where a page will break immediately below a header or a sub header.

In the following example, if I need a page break it needs to be between a paragraph and a header.

```
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<h2>Header 1.1</h2>
<p>Paragraph 1.1</p>
<h2>Header 1.2</h2>
<p>Paragraph 1.2</p>
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<h2>Header 2.1</h2>
<p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
```

I've been wrapping items that I don't want to include a break in div's with a no-break class. But how can I achieve the above? Nesting the no-breaks doesn't work.

```
@media print {
  .no-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}

<div class="no-break">
  <div class="no-break">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <h2>Header 1.1</h2>
    <p>Paragraph 1.1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="no-break">
    <h2>Header 1.2</h2>
    <p>Paragraph 1.2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="no-break">
  <h1>Header 2</h1>
  <h2>Header 2.1</h2>
  <p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
</div>
```